# Centering Column and Row Text Content in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, alignment

I want to center the content of my Columns and Rows on DataGridView.

Is there a way of doing this by specifying the Column name, like:

```
dataGridView1.Columns["CustomerName"].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
```

I want this to be applied to all the Columns of my DataGridView (which is completely coded programmatically).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this.

```
dataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
```

Comment: Will this produce same result as OP's code? I think MiddleRight will align slightly differently, but not sure.

Comment: I have corrected it. I have posted the solution for web but i realized  that the question is about windows form datagrid.

Comment: it doesn't work for radGridView in Telerik.
what am I doing for Telerik?
@Telerik

Answer (score 0):

In case if you have got `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` column in your `DataGridView` it might look like

```
var col1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
{
   HeaderText = "Month",
   Width = 40,
   DefaultCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle()
   {
      Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
      ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
   }
};

dataGridView.Columns.Add(col1);
```